# Pure Angular Cloudant connection

Tags: angular, cloudant

Iam trying to connect to my cloudant using just angular. The first post is successful and I am able to retrive a document/view from the cloudant with the first get method.

But when I do a successive post method I am getting a 401 unauthorised error message. Could someone please explain me what error I am doing here. Please reply in detail as I am newbie with angular and cloudant (RESTful arch)

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
const ACCOUNTNAME = 'my acc';
const APIKEY = 'my key';
const APIPASSWORD = 'my pass';
const DATABASE = 'my db';
var cloudantDoc = 'link of document to update';

app.controller('tutorialCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
//Authentication header settings
var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://'+ACCOUNTNAME+'.cloudant.com/_session',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    data: 'name='+APIKEY+'&password='+APIPASSWORD,
    withCredentials: true
}

$http(req).then(function(result){
                    //Grab data
                    req = {
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: 'https://'+ACCOUNTNAME+'.cloudant.com/'+DATABASE+'/_design/AllClients/_view/AllClients',
                        withCredentials: true

                    }

                    $http(req).then(function(result){
                                        $scope.tableData = result.data;
                                        console.log(result);
                                    },
                                    function(){
                                        console.log("Failed at grabbing data");
                                    });

                }, 
                function(){
                    console.log('Failed at authenticating');
                }
);

$scope.revisionNumNews;

    $http.post(cloudantDoc, JSON.stringify({"_id": "CLient1", "Client_Name":"ABC", "_rev": ""})).success(function(response){
                revisionNumNews = response.rev;

            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code you have `var cloudantDoc = 'link of document to update'`, if you are trying to update an existing document you will need to make a PUT request instead of a POST. in any case, your request should include the `{withCredentials: true}` option.

if you are trying to create a new document try changing your POST request to something like this:

```
var databaseUrl = 'https://' + ACCOUNTNAME + '.cloudant.com/' + DATABASE  

$http.post(databaseUrl, {'_id':'CLient1', 'Client_Name':'ABC'}, {withCredentials: true})
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.revisionNumNews = response.rev
    })
```

however, if you are trying to update an existing document your will need to make a PUT request and also include the document's latest `_rev`. it would look something like this:

```
var databaseUrl = 'https://' + ACCOUNTNAME + '.cloudant.com/' + DATABASE  

$http.put(databaseUrl + '/' + cloudantDocId, cloudantDoc, {withCredentials: true})
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.revisionNumNews = response.rev
    })
```

where `cloudantDocId` is the document id of the document getting updated and `cloudantDoc` is the updated document object (with the latest `_rev`)